# Docker inside Docker in a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, chown

I am trying to run a Jenkins pod in a Kubernetes cluster on bare metal.

I was trying to implement docker in docker as I need to build a Docker image in a pipeline so I mount /var/run/docker.sock as a volume into the container. 
Problem I faced was that I was receiving permission denied error each time a docker command run in the Jenkins pipeline.

I checked the `/var/run/docker.sock` ownership on the node

```
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Apr 10 19:47 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Then I checked it inside the running container:

```
srw-rw---- 1 root 116 0 Apr 10 21:33 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now I am a bit confused. Why I see an ID? I checked the groupID of the `docker` group on the host. It is exactly 116. I guess logical assumption would be that ownership inside the container is exactly the same as on the host. Though the docker group on the host is not seeing as a docker group inside the container. Is that the correct assumption? Then tThe question is: what did I do wrong?

My Jenkins Dockerfile looks as following

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.230-jdk11
....
UN apt-get update -qq  && apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

#The following 3 commands I tried to fix the issue, but it did not help
RUN touch /var/run/docker.sock
RUN chown jenkins:docker /var/run/docker.sock
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

I assume that the groups could be either 
- somehow mapped between host and guest OSs (not sure it works this way(does it?))
or
- jenkins user should be added to the docker group on the host OS, but I failed to find how.
Probably it could be done as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270070/permission-denied-when-connecting-to-docker-daemon-on-jenkinsci-blueocean-image) with the command on a pod start, but then I would have to run the pod as a user that has rights to do so, which might be not the best idea.
or
- something else

Please advise, what is the advised way to have this working.

Thank you

PS
The issue can be clearly fixed by having

```
  securityContext:
    ..
    runAsGroup: 116
    ..
```

in the deployment definition, but it is not a valid solution.

Comment: Not an answer as such but there are tools designed to do image builds in containers like [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) and [buildah](https://buildah.io/). Much less hassle that dind and has the benefit of less security issues too

Comment: Thanks, @Matt, for the advise. I will look into the tools. For now I am trying to understand how it should be done in general with or without tools. Just having troubles to find information how this security matter is designed and the proper way to configure in real life.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to run docker in kubernetes.

1. Do you really need docker or do you just need to build a container?  If you just want to build docker containers img, kaniko, and buildah will build docker images.
2. Jenkins can create a kubernetes pod with multiple containers.  Different stages can use different containers, and share the same build dir. See https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/
3. Do you have a system you can use as a docker build host or jenkins agent?  If only a few builds need docker then maybe it's worth it to use a normal agent or a docker build host.
4. Actually use Docker in Docker.  Danger Danger https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/
5. Use something like sysbox or kubevirt to run a VM.